# Stack smashing not fires. Why?

Tags: c++, c, glibc, stack-smash

I'm trying to make glibc detect stack smashing, and I use the following code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 static const int n = 5;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
  if (argc != 2)
  {
     printf("usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
     return -1;
  }
  printf("%s, len = %d\n", argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
  unsigned char a[n][n];
  unsigned char * b = a[n - 1];
  memcpy(b, argv[1], (strlen(argv[1]) + 1) * sizeof(unsigned char));
  return 0;
 }
```

If argv[1] length greater than 5, I expect detection of stack smashing error, however, I do not, and valgrind detects no errors. What I should change to get this error? (array a must be two-dimensional)

Comment: It's _undefined_ behavior.

Comment: @MM.: Indeed.  But the OP is asking how to get tools to detect this sort of issue (I think).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth As the array sizes are known during compile time, the compiler might decide to copy only the first `n` bytes, not smashing the stack at all.

Comment: @arne char array[10]; gets(array); gets a stack smash if string with length greater than 10 is inputed.

Comment: Actually the compiler can simply discard anything past the second `printf`.

Comment: How did you compile this? (you tagged both c and c++)

Comment: @Anton: Again, undefined behaviour. The compiler can do with this whatever it wants. It may even build in bounds checking and let the program explode gracefully.

Comment: People, stop with this "Undefined Behavior" standardese. This question isn't about **ISO** C++, this is about `glibc`. If you want to nitpick, ask about the CPU. That matters.

Comment: Undefined behavior means that what you have coded does not "mean anything valid to the compiler".  So it can replace the offending part of the code with no code at all, or exit, or anything else the compiler designer decides to do with stuff like this.  In other words you cannot depend on your code to do what you wrote.

Comment: What happens if you make `n = 1`? Does the result change? What argument lengths have you tried? Did you disassemble the program and see exactly how it manages the stack frame? Have you investigated _when_ glibc checks for stack smashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the logic in gcc which decides when to enable stack protection is slightly tricky. First note from the docs:

> -fstack-protector
>
> Emit extra code to check for buffer overflows, such as stack smashing attacks. This is done by adding a guard variable to functions with vulnerable objects. This includes functions that call alloca, and **functions with buffers larger than 8 bytes**. The guards are initialized when a function is entered and then checked when the function exits. If a guard check fails, an error message is printed and the program exits

So, we should expect a function with local buffers smaller than 8 bytes to be unprotected. For example, this:

```
int unprotected() {
    char a[5];
    strcpy(a, "this is much too long");
    return a[0];
}
```

compiled with `gcc -fstack-protector -Wstack-protector`, gives a warning like

> warning: stack protector not protecting function: all local arrays are less than 8 bytes long [-Wstack-protector]

So, you might think your `char[5][5]` will be protected, since it is more than 8 bytes long. However, when I compile that to assembler, I get no warning *or* stack protection (you can find the assembler to look for in [this Dr. Dobbs article](http://www.drdobbs.com/security/anatomy-of-a-stack-smashing-attack-and-h/240001832)). It seems that gcc treats it as 5 buffers of 5 bytes each instead of a single buffer of 25 bytes.

You can persuade gcc to enable stack protection either by showing it a single buffer larger than 8 bytes:

```
void protected(char *arg) {
    union {
        char dummy[5 * 5];
        char a[5][5];
    } u;
    memcpy(u.a[4], arg, (strlen(arg) + 1));
}
```

or by simply using `-fstack-protector-all`.

Comment: Single buffer larger than 8 bytes did not get this error, it seems to be still unprotected, but -fstack-protector-all helped. Thanks.

Comment: And, never name functions with the word "protected" =)

Comment: Good point! I'll leave it now, with the caveat that I was thinking in C

Answer (score 3):

By default, GCC only adds code to detect stack smashing when you do something particularly dangerous like `alloca` (or `gets`, as you mention in a comment), or declare a large automatic array.

If you want to enable protection for all functions, use the `-fstack-protector-all` option. You can also request a warning about unprotected functions with `-Wstack-protector`.

Comment: Mike, is there an exact value for "large" number you mentioned?

Comment: @Anton: According to the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options), 8 bytes. But that doesn't seem to match what you're seeing, so the documentation may not entirely match reality.